# How to change location of username and password in Customer Portal email

Tags: customer-portal, email-template

I have a very nice branded professional looking HTML email template for the New User Email Template for the email that gets sent for a new Customer Portal user.

The issue is that SF just appends the Username and Password on two separate lines after the entire email template in the email, making it look a lot less professional and out of place with the rest of the email.  (Picture a nice centered HTML page with a border forming a box like look and then a few blank lines with plain text Username and Password left justified on their own lines outside of the box).

How can I get the Username and Password field to be part of the actual Email template?  I don't see them in the merge fields.  I'd be willing to move to a Visualforce template if that would work.

Am I just missing something?

If there is no way around it, I'd be very disappointed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it is not possible.  There is an Idea to "Make New User Template Email Notification in Customer Portal more professional" http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007XMqAAM.

The only problem is that the Idea is old so maybe it has been fixed and I just can't find out how (There is a 3 month old comment, though).

I'm 99% sure that there is no support for it.  Salesforce did a half-you-know-what job with this (frustrated).

Comment: Considering the partner portal emails for salesforce's own partner portal suffer form this issue I'm pretty sure you're right.

Comment: For now, the most acceptable solution is to try to make the username and password seem like a part of the email by including a message that reads something like "Please find your username and password below" and then don't include borders around your content and don't center it (do left align).

Comment: Thanks Peter. We are facing the same issue. Is there any other workaround available such as Visualforce template?

Comment: @RichardN - No.  That won't work. In VF email templates you can access the Username for Users, but there is no Password field. The only other thing that I could think of would be to use CSS to move the username and password elsewhere inside the template, but depending on the CSS it might not render all that great in the various email clients and if SF changes how they render it, then it could break.  The most acceptable solution that I found was just to add a message such as find your username and password below.

Comment: Thanks. I finally had to change a great looking letterhead template in order to accommodate this problem.