# Changing the position of login information in password reset / New user email template

Tags: email-template, mail-merge

If I create a new user for my portal through my force.com site (Develop -> Sites), 
it triggers an email to the user with the username and password appended at the end.

**I have to change the position of this username and password text to the middle of my email template that i have set in my portal. is it possible?**

Here is the link stating my issue :-
https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000KR85AAG

Comment: Basically the same question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-to-change-location-of-username-and-password-in-customer-portal-email -- Cannot do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to customize the new user email template.

The password is added to the end of the email, just fix your email template to have that addition look normal.

Sample email:

```
Dear John Doe,

Thank you very much for your registration. To login to the site, please follow this url: http://www.bogus.com

The security team has provided you with the following username and password, please keep them safe, and meet you on our site.

[SALESFORCE WILL ADD THE DATA HERE]
```