# Remove username from Customer Portal Confirmation Email

Tags: email, customer-portal, email-template, user, registration

I am attempting to modify the username of the confirmation e-mail for the Customer Portal that I have setup. I have created a custom login and am populating the @something.com portion of the username behind the scenes of the login page. This makes the username@something.com portion of the confirmation e-mail unwanted and I just want to display a different field or modify the existing field. I have added a disclaimer that states to ignore the @something.com portion of the email but would rather remove it.

the stackexchange post below was posted a while ago and I have not seen if there were any updates since then so I thought I would ask if anyone else has seen something:

[How to change location of username and password in Customer Portal email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-to-change-location-of-username-and-password-in-customer-portal-email)

Thanks for any tips or direction on where to head at this point.